# How can I use fieldsets in a form with CSS grid?

Tags: css, html, css-grid

I want to use `<fieldset>` for the semantic HTML.
I'm using CSS grid to make my form look nice.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, max-content) minmax(200px, max-content) minmax(200px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.field__label {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">

  <label class="field__label" for="first-names">
             First names
  </label>

  <input class="form__entry" id="first-names" type="text" name="firstName">

  <span class="form__feedback form__instructions">
            Must only use letters, spaces, hyphens and apostrophes
    </span>

</form>
```

This all works nicely (and in my real form I have the `<label>` -> `<input>` -> `<span>` pattern repeated several times).

The problem is - if I wrap a few instances of that pattern in a `<fieldset>` which I want to do for personal details, bank details etc, because then the `<fieldset>`s are the direct descendents of the element with `display: grid;` it places those in the grid, and not the form elements. How can I get round this?

Comment: read this : https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's really useful and does the trick - slight problem in that if I want to add a `<legend>` at the start of the fieldset it messes the grid up again. Is there any way of having a 'fake' item that I could slot in columns 2 and 3 on that row?

Comment: You can maybe try pseudo element to create these fake elements

Comment: I've done an empty couple of `<span>`s and it works, but it doesn't feel very semantic! If we can come up with a legit way of making it work, I'd be happy to accept your answer if you write it as one.

Comment: you need to give more detail about the second part ;) how you will add legend, etc so you may edit your question

Comment: have asked and answered that bit here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576999/make-a-single-row-in-css-grid-span-all-columns/50577000#50577000 as it's a different thing really. Make an answer for this one and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. If you strictly want to go with CSS grid layout you need to use this

   ```
   fieldset {
     display: contents;
   }
   ```

   However, this will eliminate the fielset from the view so there is no way to get a border, etc. You can still style the legend.
2. In case you want to have the fieldset display normally with border, etc. you need to change your layout. Here is an example that may work as a starting point:

   ```
   fieldset > label, form > label {
     clear: both;
     float: left;
     width: 18%;
     text-align: right;
     font-weight: bold;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   fieldset>label {
     margin-right: 0.5em;
     padding-top: 0.1em;
   }
   form>label {
     margin-left: 0.75em;
     margin-right: 0.5em;
     padding-top: 0.1em;
   }
   fieldset>:not(label):not(legend) {
     min-width: 72%;
     width: 72%;
     margin-bottom: 0.5em;
     display: block;
   }
   form>:not(label):not(fieldset) {
     min-width: 70%;
     width: 70%;
     margin-bottom: 0.5em;
     display: block;
   }
   ```

Comment: We should be mindful of browser coverage of `display: contents`, which is still quite limited: https://caniuse.com/?search=display%3A%20contents. Note that there was a very bad implementation bug for some older chromium browsers and safari is noted as being particularly buggy, as of 2022.