# make a single row in CSS grid span all columns

Tags: css, html, css-grid

How I can make the `<legend>` span all rows, so it will mess up the `<fieldset>` which is styled as a 3 column CSS grid?

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personal Details</legend>
  <label class="field__label" for="first-names">
            First names
        </label>
  <input class="form__entry" id="first-names" type="text" name="firstName">
  <span class="form__feedback form__instructions">
            Must only use letters, spaces, hyphens and apostrophes
        </span>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, max-content) minmax(200px, max-content) minmax(200px,1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

fieldset {
    display: contents;
}
```

Comment: Question unclear . Can you share a photo of your expectation?

Comment: You should include enough code for us to replicate the problem, some CSS would be useful here. Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe it is better to use:

```css
fieldset legend {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

Or if you only need 3 columns

```css
fieldset legend {
  grid-column: 1/ span 3;
}
```

Comment: That does look better, the 4 is counter-intuitive! Will test

Answer (score 0):

Apply

```
fieldset legend {
    grid-column: 1/4;
}
```

to the CSS. This makes it span three columns.